# Call of Duty: Black Ops 2 controller issues

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

On Call of Duty: Black Ops 2 the controller goes down when I want to go up and up when I want to go down. How do I fix this?

Comment: It is.I never knew that.

Answer (score 2):

Go into the settings/options and fix your inversion settings. That's really all there is to it.